# When to use scoped or public variables?

Tags: function, variables

I am having some confusion between when to use a scoped variable. When you declare it in a function like this.

```
int main(){
int x;
}
```

And when to use a public variable like this.

```
int x;

int main(){
}
```

The scoped variable being the one only available in the function it is declared in and the public variable being the one available to the entire file. Could you help me understand when to use this?

Comment: Which language is this in? C/C++, I'm assuming?

Comment: Yes this is in languages like c/c++.

Comment: Always limit the scope of a variable as much as possible.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand the reason for this.

Comment: When you have a dozen or so functions, all using the same global, the surface are for bugs related to the value of the global at any given point in the program increases. If you narrow the scope, the surface area reduces to the scope of the variable. It also makes the function much easier to put under unit test. Read about dependency injection and pure functions. They are related in how broad scope makes things difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask these questions to you,

Do you intent to use x in main function only? 
Are you going to pass x as parameter to mains subfunctions?
Then it should be scoped. 
Createors of modular programming will be happy to see this

Does your app consist of many files? 
Is x is something (like global state) which your app needs  in all those files? 
Then x should be kept global (in header file , as best practice) so it can be used as extern in other files.

If you are just starting to write your app:
If you start x as a scope varible and end up passing it in every function across all files then you should change it as global scope

If your app is already developed and x is being added as a new functionality:
Then you should be already knowing x represents global state or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple rule of thumb: *declare a variable in the narrowest possible scope in which you'll be using it.*

---

As for an explanation of *why*: in C and C++ (and other languages), variables essentially "cease to exist" when they go out of scope. If you declare a variable outside of a function, that variable gets processed and stored in memory before the function is called. Each time you call the function and use that variable, the same bit of memory is accessed, and as a result the variable maintains its value between calls.

Meanwhile, if you declare a variable *inside* a function (for example; in C/C++, I think anything with curly brackets in it defines a narrower scope), it gets allocated and stored in memory *only when it comes into scope*. When that scope ends (e.g. with a `return` statement at the end of a method), all the memory that was in that scope is released.

This all ties into the *stack*, which is one of the two main ways that C and C++ handle dynamic memory. [Here's a serviceable overview of how C programs lay out memory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/); suffice it to say that the reasons for the rule of thumb above are that

- *you don't want to consume any more memory than you need at any given time*. In other words, you don't want a variable sitting around that you're never going to use.
- It's much easier to debug a problem when the variable has a limited scope, and you know everything that could be affecting it, than when it's in the global scope and *everything* could be affecting it